# How to stop horizontal scrolling on iphone 11

Tags: html, css, iphone, hidden, horizontal-scrolling

I cant stop the website from horizontal-scrolling on iphone but on android its fine, Im not sure what I did wrong, would appreciate any help

html/css

```
  <!--  https://jsfiddle.net/tL2qeoad/ -->
```